create multiple div in a row, dynamically using a loop
I want to create some div dynamically, like in the image shown below. There could be 30+ div aligned like that, so hardcoding that will be painful. I want to do it with a loop. I tried many weird things that didn't work. And the loop right now does not make sense, since I'm hardcoding everything in the loop.
How can I make it so that it is created in the loop, without repeating the code? So like a row having 4 or 5 cols. And also, if I change the dbRes to be 20 or some other number, it should create the rows accordingly?
I have this code
const SearchRes = () => {
    const dbRes = 10;
    let res = null;

    const user = {            
        uname: 'Piggy',
        lang: 'English',
        country: 'England',
        level: 'Noob'
    }

    const divInfo = 
        <div style={{border: '2px solid red', width: '200px'}}>
            <p>Name:&nbsp;{user.uname}</p>
            <p>Language:&nbsp;{user.lang}</p>
            <p>Count:&nbsp;{user.country}</p>
            <p>Level:&nbsp;{user.level}</p>
        </div>
    
    for (let i = 0; i < dbRes; ++i) {
       res =  
            <>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    {divInfo}
                </Col>

                <Col>
                    {divInfo}
                </Col>

                <Col>
                    {divInfo}
                </Col>

                <Col>
                    {divInfo}
                </Col>

                <Col>
                    {divInfo}
                </Col>                
            </Row>                
            </>                          
    }    
    
    return (
        <Container>
            {res}
        </Container>
        
    )
}

I searched for some similar problems, and the closest I found was this: is there a way to create multiple divs using a loop in React
But it didn't help me
Thanks in advance


React uses the array map function to achieve this.
See the official docs here.
If it's strictly based on an index # I would use:
const dbRes = 10;
return(
<Container>
  {[...Array(dbRes).keys()].map(x => (
     <Row>
       <Col>{divInfo}</Col>
       {//etc.}
     </Row>
    ))
  }
</Container>
)

If you have a list of user through, this would be a preferred solution:
const users = [{uname: 'Piggy', lang: 'English', country: 'England', level: 'Noob'}]

return(
<Container>
  {users.map(user => (
       <div style={{border: '2px solid red', width: '200px'}}>
            <p>Name:&nbsp;{user.uname}</p>
            <p>Language:&nbsp;{user.lang}</p>
            <p>Count:&nbsp;{user.country}</p>
            <p>Level:&nbsp;{user.level}</p>
       </div>
     )
   )
  }
</Container>

Also a React fragment is not necessary here as Row wraps the whole component.
